# `@post.userview.users << current_user`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

Every post has a userview, and each userview has many users. I want one single many to many to have a simple `.add()` and `.remove()` function like django. How do I place the `current_user` into the many-to-many relationship of the views?

I found this:

```
@post.userview.users << current_user
```

But it brings up some SQL error. It's suggesting I add a post_id:

```
ERROR:  column userviews.post_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "userviews".* FROM "userviews" WHERE "userviews"."po...
                                                     ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "userviews.posts_id".
```

After the answer, now the error is:

```
can't write unknown attribute `userview_id`
```

Because I changed the migrations around a little, userview has references to posts and users. Post has_one userview, has_many users through userview, userview has_many posts and has_many users.

```
create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "userview_id"
    t.bigint "userviews_id"
    t.index ["userviews_id"], name: "index_posts_on_userviews_id"
  end

create_table "userviews", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "users_id"
    t.bigint "posts_id"
    t.integer "post_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["posts_id"], name: "index_userviews_on_posts_id"
    t.index ["users_id"], name: "index_userviews_on_users_id"
  end





class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :viewed_posts, through: :userview, class_name: 'Post'
...


class Userview < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :user
end


class Post < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :userviews
    has_many :viewers, through: :userview, class_name: 'User'
...


Could not find the source association(s) "viewer" or :viewers in model Userview. Try 'has_many :viewers, :through => :userviews, :source => <name>'. Is it one of post or user?
```

Although, that's for `unless @post.viewers.include?(current_user)`

Comment: Looks like you have some errors in your associations. Please, add `schema.rb` and models files to the question

Comment: @Vasilisa updated

Comment: And please users table in schema, and User, Userview and Post models (app/models/user.rb etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood correctly what are you trying to achieve, but I'll try to fix your associations.

To associate 2 models you need to store foreign key in one of them. Model which stores the key `belongs_to` other model. Eg in `posts` table you have `user_id` column, it means Post `belongs_to: user` and User `has_many :posts` (or `has_one :post` if you need one-to-one association). For such association you can write:

```
user = User.first
post = Post.last
user.posts << post
```

If you want all this stuff to work automatically you should follow the convention about naming. Foreign keys should be in singular form, like `user_id`, not `users_id`

If you want many-to-many association you need to create an intermediate table, which stores both foreign keys. It can be done using simple direct `has_and_belongs_to_many` association or with more complex `has_many through:`

I suppose that in your case it should be:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :userviews
  # it is posts viewed by the user
  # you need to specify class name because it differs from association name
  has_many :viewed_posts, through: :userviews, class_name: 'Post' 

  # posts written by the user
  has_many :posts 
end

class Userview < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :userviews
  has_many :viewers, through: :userviews, source: :user
end
```

It means that you need `post_id` and `user_id` columns in `userviews` table and `user_id` in `posts` table. Please, remove useless columns and add needed in migration. When you set it all correctly you'll be able to do

```
@post.viewers << current_user
```

to add `current_user` to viewers list. Corresponding userview instance is created automagically

Comment: Thank you, that's really close to it, but getting the following error, I'll update.

Comment: Do I need t.references :users in the posts for the viewers?

Comment: @AdenHandasyde happy to help you! Updated my answer,  I was in a hurry and made a mistake about `source`. Great, that you solved the error yourself. You don't need ` t.references :users` in the posts for the viewers, all needed references are inside `userviews` table

Answer (score 0):

Changed `has_many :viewers, through: :userviews, class_name: 'User'`

to `has_many :viewers, through: :userviews, source: :user`